# Does $|x_{n+m}|\leq |x_n+x_m|$ imply the convergence of $\{x_n/n\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> If $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence of real numbers satisfying $$|x_{n+m}|\leq |x_n+x_m|\qquad \text{for all }n,m\in\mathbb N_{\geq 1},\tag{$*$}$$
> then does the limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n}{n}$ exist?

**Ideas.**
It follows from $(*)$ and the induction that $|x_n|\leq n|x_1|$ for all $n\in\mathbb N_{\geq 1}$, hence $\{x_n/n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is a bounded sequence. On the other hand, $(*)$ also implies that $|x_{n+m}|\le |x_n|+|x_m|$ for all $n,m\in\mathbb N_{\geq 1}$, hence by [Fekete's subadditive lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subadditivity#Sequences) we get the convergence of $\{|x_n|/n\}_{n\geq 1}$ with
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|x_n|}n=\inf_{n\geq 1}\frac{|x_n|}n.$$
However, these results cannot deduce the convergence of $\{x_n/n\}_{n\geq 1}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $|x_n|/n \to L.$ If $L = 0,$ we're done, so assume $L > 0.$ For $n$ large enough, $x_n/n$ is very close to either $L$ or $-L.$ If past a certain $n$ they are close to the same, then $\frac{x_n}{n}$ converges. Otherwise, infinitely many terms are close to either. Pick $m, n$ large enough with $x_n \approx nL, x_m \approx -mL,$ then $$(n+m)L \approx |x_{n+m}| \le |x_n + x_m| \approx |n-m|L,$$ contradiction. You can turn this into a rigorous $\epsilon-N$ argument.

Upon Feng's request: Fix $\epsilon = L/2$ and pick $N \ge 3L$ such that $|\frac{|x_n|}{n} - L| < \epsilon$ for $n \ge N.$ Pick $m, n \ge N$ as before with $|m-n| = 1,$ which is possible.

Then $$3L \le (n+m)(L - \epsilon) \le |x_{n+m}| \le |x_n + x_m| \le |n-m|(L+\epsilon) \le 2L,$$ contradiction.

Comment: Looks fine except for a missing absolute value sign.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please write some details about the rigorous $\epsilon-N$ argument? Because $|\frac{x_n}n-L|<\epsilon$ implies that $|x_n-nL|<n\epsilon$, which does not imply that $x_n\approx nL$ if $n$ is large. In view of this, It seems that the "rigorous $\epsilon-N$ argument" may be not as easy as we think.

Comment: @Feng I've updated the answer, let me know if you want even more rigor.