# Does $|\vec x_{n+m}|\leq |\vec x_n+\vec x_m|$ imply the convergence of $\{\vec x_n/n\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, multivariable-calculus

> Let $d\geq 1$ be a positive integer. If $\{\vec x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence of $d$-dimensional vectors satisfying $$|\vec x_{n+m}|\leq |\vec x_n+\vec x_m|\qquad \text{for all }n,m\in\mathbb N_{\geq 1},\tag{$*$}$$
> where $|\vec x|=[(x^{(1)})^2+\cdots+(x^{(d)})^2]^{1/2}$ for $\vec x=(x^{(1)}, \cdots, x^{(d)})$. Then does the limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\vec x_n}{n}$ exist?

**Ideas.** It follows from $(*)$ and the induction that $|\vec x_n|\leq n|\vec x_1|$ for all $n\in\mathbb N_{\geq 1}$, hence $\{\vec x_n/n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is a bounded sequence. On the other hand, $(*)$ also implies that $|\vec x_{n+m}|\le |\vec x_n|+|\vec x_m|$ for all $n,m\in\mathbb N_{\geq 1}$, hence by [Fekete's subadditive lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subadditivity#Sequences) we get the convergence of $\{|\vec x_n|/n\}_{n\geq 1}$ with
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|\vec x_n|}n=\inf_{n\geq 1}\frac{|\vec x_n|}n.$$

If $d=1$, then the answer is *yes*, which is proved in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4788504/624428). For $d\geq2$, I tried to use the same ideas as in that post. If $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{|\vec x_n|}n=L$, then for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N\gg L$ such that $\left|\frac{|\vec x_n|}n-L\right|<\varepsilon$ for all $n>N$. Take $\varepsilon>0$ small enough. Fix $n_0>N$, then there exists $\vec z_1$ with $|\vec z_1|=1$ such that $\left|\frac{\vec x_{n_0}}{n_0}-L\vec z_1\right|<\varepsilon$. Let $n$ be the largest integer such that $\left|\frac{\vec x_{k}}{k}-L\vec z_1\right|<\varepsilon$ holds for all $n_0\leq k\leq n$. Then $\left|\frac{\vec x_{n}}{n}-L\vec z_1\right|<\varepsilon$ and $\left|\frac{\vec x_{n+1}}{n+1}-L\vec z_1\right|\geq\varepsilon$, hence $\left|\frac{\vec x_{n+1}}{n+1}-L\vec z_2\right|\geq\varepsilon$ for some $\vec z_2$ with $|\vec z_2|=1$ and $\vec z_2$ is far away from $\vec z_1$. However, they are not as far away as in that post, where $\vec z_1=1, \vec z_2=-1$ for $d=1$. I'm not sure how to continue.

In fact, I suspect that the answer for $d\geq 2$ is negative. But I cannot find a counterexpamle.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose
$$ \liminf \frac{|x_n|}{n} = c > 0. $$

Then we have

$$ \frac{|x_{m+n}|^2}{(m+n)^2} \leq \frac{|x_m + x_n|^2}{(m+n)^2} = \frac{|x_m|^2 + 2|x_m||x_n|\cos\theta_{mn} + |x_n|^2}{(m+n)^2} $$

$$ \liminf_{m,n\to\infty} \frac{|x_{m+n}|^2}{(m+n)^2} \leq \liminf_{m,n\to\infty} \frac{|x_m|^2 + 2|x_m||x_n|\cos\theta_{mn} + |x_n|^2}{(m+n)^2} $$

$$ c^2 \leq \liminf_{m,n\to\infty} \frac{m^2c^2 + 2mnc^2\cos\theta_{mn} + n^2c^2}{(m+n)^2} $$

The RHS of the last step is intuitive because, in the limit, $\frac{|x_n|}{n}$ is approximately $c$, but requires some rigorous justification. My way of doing this is a bit messy, so I'd appreciate if someone can suggest a neater way.

> Consider the error term introduced by replacing the $|x_n|^2$ part
> with $c^2n^2$. This is
>
> $$ \frac{|x_n|^2 - c^2n^2}{(m+n)^2}$$ Which is smaller than
> $$\frac{|x_n|^2 - c^2n^2}{n^2} = \frac{|x_n|^2}{n^2} - c^2. $$
>
> Now, we know
>
> $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{|x_n|^2}{n^2} - c^2 = 0, $$
>
> so the error term goes to $0$. The same applies to the $|x_m|^2$ error
> term.
>
> The $|x_m||x_n|$ error term is nastier:
>
> $$ \frac{2|x_m||x_n|\cos\theta_{mn} - 2c^2mn\cos\theta_{mn}}{(m+n)^2}$$
> $$= 2\cos\theta_{mn} \frac{|x_m||x_n| - c^2mn}{(m+n)^2}. $$
>
> $2\cos\theta_{mn}$ is bounded, and
>
> $$ \frac{|x_m||x_n| - c^2mn}{(m+n)^2} \leq \frac{|x_m||x_n| -
>  c^2mn}{mn}, $$
>
> which goes to $0$ for the same reason as $\frac{|x_n|^2 -
>  c^2n^2}{n^2}$

So the RHS is justified, and we can return to where we were and divide through by $c^2$ to find

$$ 1 \leq \liminf_{m,n\to\infty} \frac{m^2 + 2mn\cos\theta_{mn} + n^2}{(m+n)^2} $$

But,

$$ \frac{m^2 + 2mn\cos\theta_{mn} + n^2}{(m+n)^2} \leq 1 $$

So,

$$ \liminf_{m,n\to\infty} \frac{m^2 + 2mn\cos\theta_{mn} + n^2}{(m+n)^2} = 1 $$

Hence,

$$ \liminf_{m,n\to\infty} \cos\theta_{mn} = \lim_{m,n\to\infty} \cos\theta_{mn} = 1 $$

But then, $ \frac{x_m}m $ and $ \frac{x_n}n $ are two vectors whose magnitudes limit to the same thing, $ c $, and the angle between them limits to $0$. So, as $ m,n  \to \infty $, $ |\frac{x_m}m - \frac{x_n}n| $ goes to $0$.

It's a Cauchy sequence, so it limits.

---

To elaborate on that last part,

$$ |\frac{x_n}n - \frac{x_m}m|^2 = \frac{|x_m|^2}{m^2} - \frac{2|x_m||x_n|\cos\theta_{mn}}{mn} + \frac{|x_n|^2}{n^2} $$

So,

$$ \lim_{m,n \to \infty} |\frac{x_n}n - \frac{x_m}m|^2 = \lim_{m,n \to \infty} \frac{|x_m|^2}{m^2} - \lim_{m,n \to \infty} \frac{2|x_m||x_n|\cos\theta_{mn}}{mn} + \lim_{m,n \to \infty} \frac{|x_n|^2}{n^2}$$
$$= c^2 - 2c^2 + c^2 = 0 $$

Hence,

$$ \lim_{m,n \to \infty} |\frac{x_n}n - \frac{x_m}m| = 0 $$

So, $\frac{x_n}n$ is Cauchy.

Comment: Can you elaborate how the term $\liminf_{m,n\to\infty} \frac{|x_m|^2 + 2|x_m||x_n|\cos\theta_{mn} + |x_n|^2}{(m+n)^2}$ is estimated? The lim inf of a sum is $\ge$ the sum of lim infs, and the $\cos$ term can be positive or negative. – I am not saying that anything is wrong, only that more details would be helpful.

Comment: @MartinR I think I've fixed it, but it's a bit of a mess now.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't think that $$ \liminf_{m,n\to\infty} \frac{m^2 + 2mn\cos\theta_{mn} + n^2}{(m+n)^2} = 1 $$ implies $$ \liminf_{m,n\to\infty} \cos\theta_{mn} = \lim_{m,n\to\infty} \cos\theta_{mn} = 1. $$ Consider $\theta_{m,n}$ satisfying $\cos\theta_{m,m^2}=1/2$ and $\cos\theta_{m,n}=1$ for $n\neq m^2$ (If I understand it correctly.)

Comment: @Feng, such an arrangement of points isn't possible. If $\cos\theta_{mn}=1$, then $x_m$ and $x_n$ are the same, up to rescaling, so $$\theta_{mm^2} = \theta_{nm^2}$$

Comment: @ZoeAllen OK. Then what about $\cos \theta_{m,m^2}=\cos\theta_{m^2, m}=1/2$ and $\cos\theta_{m,n}=1$ otherwise?

Comment: @Feng I think you might have misunderstood why your previous example doesn't work. The issue is that e.g. $\cos\theta_{3,8}=1$ implies $x_3$ and $x_8$ point in the same direction, so if $\cos\theta_{3,9}=\frac12$, $\cos\theta_{8,9}=\frac12$ too. Your new example has the same problem.